# How to create reusable PowerShell functions in the Visual Studio solution

Tags: powershell, nuget-package

We are using some custom scaffolders in the Visual Studio 2012 solution as well as some built-in ones (e.g. Code First Migrations commands). We run then in the Package Manager Console and Using PowerShell we can combine them in useful functions that do several tasks at ones.

For example we have several projects with Migrations and we want to execute the Update-Database cmdlet for each of them writing only one command. Something like that:

```
"Project1", "Project2", "Project3", "Project4" | ForEach-Object {Update-Database -StartUpProjectName $_ -ProjectName $_}
```

It works just fine but we want to have a command like

```
Update-All
```

That would do the same without need to type the previous thing. And we want to have it available for all developers as a part of the solution then get from source control.

Any ideas how to do this kind of thing?

**EDIT:** Keith Hill suggestion about using a powershell profile works good. I'm also looking at using Import-Module cmdlet from the Nuget. I want to actually have very smooth workflow of managing the reusable cmdlets in the project. Any ideas how to have the Import-Module executed for the solution? It it possible to write a custom (private) Nuget package without hosting it and have it execute the init.ps that would Import-Module?

Comment: Could you include some more info? not familiar with VS and their cmdlets. Is `Update-Database` a VS-cmdlet or 3rd-party? What Directory is the commands run from in package manager console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each PowerShell gets its own profile.  You can see the path for the profile file that NuGet expects by running this command in the PM console:

```
PM> $profile
C:\Users\Keith\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\NuGet_profile.ps1
```

Edit that file, add your function e.g.

```
function Update-All {
   "Project1", "Project2", "Project3", "Project4" | 
       ForEach-Object {Update-Database -StartUpProjectName $_ -ProjectName $_}
}
```

The next time your start Visual Studio that function will be available in your PM console. 
You can parameterize the function as needed.  You can put this profile in source control but each dev is going to need to copy it into their Documents\WindowsPowerShell dir.

Comment: Very good hint thank you Keith, it works! I want to actually dig a bit deeper. See my comment at the post